# Static file download from custom folder in Angular 7

Tags: typescript, angular7, assets

I am trying to download a static file from assets folder. It works fine when the file is placed in `images` folder and it does not work from any other folder inside assets.

```
  1. <a href="assets/images/template-users.csv" target="_self" download>
  2. <a href="assets/templates/template-users.csv" target="_self" download>
```

It works only in case 1. For case 2, it shows `Failed- No file`

Please let me know if I'm missing anything. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your angular.json? Also, is this only in production or is it also this way on your localhost

Comment: if it works in case one you might want to double check that you're building/including the templates folder in your project.

Comment: I'm testing on localhost only for now